# Necessary or unnecessary "of"

Tags: grammar, prepositions

I noticed that when there is a possesive before the noun preceding "**of**" then we cam omit "**of**" but not in the case when there's no possesive before the noun:

- I give you all (of) my love. *(Correct)*
- I give you all love. *(Incorrect)* - should be "I give you all of love"

Am I right?

I mean to say when something belongs to someone **of** can either be omitted or not but with no possesive case can we omit **of**?

Which is correct when we speak about something in general:

1. I showed him all love.
2. I showed him all of love.

Comment: In general, it would help if you said what your *intended* meaning is. Give us a paraphrase of what you want to convey. For many a grammatical utterance could be the wrong thing to say.

Comment: Why did you leave *my* out of the second example? Anyway "I give you all my love" is OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can easily give you all of my porridge. But I can give you all porridge only if I am in charge of the refectory, or perhaps one of the servers who doesn't like you and refuses to give you anything else on the menu.

**all porridge** can mean either "all the porridge that exists" or "exclusively porridge", that is, nothing but porridge.

Comment: What about "**I can give you all of porridge**"?

Comment: No, we can't use "all of" here. We always use "all", not "all of", before uncountable nouns. Check http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/quantifiers/all for your reference.

Comment: @SovereignSun: When **porridge** has no determiner, it lacks the semantic attribute of `quantity`, and thus cannot be used in a partitive construction with **all**, a quantifier. But we can say "You have a *dollop|bit|smear|splash|etc* of porridge on your shirt" since those nouns are not quantifiers.

Answer (score 0):

1. I give you all my love. (Correct)
2. I give you all of my love. (Correct)
3. I give you all love. (Correct)
4. I showed him all love. (Correct)
5. I showed him all of love. (Correct)

1 & 2 both mean that all of my love is given to you, that I do not give any of my love to anyone else.

3 means that love is the only thing that I give you, I don't give you anything else.

4 & 5 mean that I showed him everything that there is to know about love.